# how to print selected item to drop down list in HTHML

Tags: javascript

```
function myfun() {
  var x = document.getElementById('state').selectedIndex;
  var text = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;
  document.getElementById("pr").innerHTML = text;
}
```

in this code the `document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value` are fetch the value in drop down list and `document.getElementById("pr").innerHTML = text` print this value in `<div id="pr">` tag. But, value are not print. Why?

Comment: Where is `HTML` code ?

Comment: <select id="state" onchange="myfun()"> <option value="hi">hi</option> <option value="hello">hello</option> </select>

Comment: @MaulikKanani Please add relevant code in **question**.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: Apply with `text` instead of `value` [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_option_index)

```js
function myfun() {
  var x = document.getElementById('state').selectedIndex;
  var text = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].text;//its a text
  document.getElementById("pr").innerHTML = text;
}
myfun();
```

```html
<select id="state" onchange="myfun()">
  <option value="hi">hi</option>
  <option value="hello">hello</option>
</select> 
<p id="pr"></p>
```

**Alternate**

```
function myfun() {
 var x = document.getElementById('state').value;
  document.getElementById("pr").innerHTML = x
}
```

Comment: but in my case this code not work properly nothing will print

Comment: See the snippet answer its working.change the `text` instead `value` and apply with in onchange event

Comment: yes i will change the value but nothing given output

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myfun() {
  var x = document.getElementById('state').selectedIndex;
  var text = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].text;//its a text
  document.getElementById("pr").innerHTML = text;
}
myfun();
```

```html
<select id="state" onchange="myfun()">
  <option value="hi">hi</option>
  <option value="hello">hello</option>
</select> 
<p id="pr"></p>
```